# how to adjust nav bar in the bootstrap page header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to build a website.In normal view (on laptop) logo should be in the right and menu in the left.  The problem comes in mobile view where the menu items appear on the left while I want them on the right(under the logo).
The menu items on mobile view always refer to the nav alignment of normal view only.

this is the case I'm looking for[image]

Here is the css file and html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">LOGO<img src="img/logob.png" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {

  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul{ list-style:none;}
img{ max-width:100%;}
.logo{
          float:right;
          margin-bottom:4px;
          margin-top:4px;
        }   
.nav{float:left;}
```

Comment: It's better to give a working exemple

Comment: I added a picture, see it please

Answer (score 0):

I added float left to navbar toggle and float right on mobile for navbar nav
[here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0av337Ld/1/)

```
.navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
}
}
```